# System.UriFormatException

Tags: c#, matlab

I'm facing a problem in c# `System.URI.FormatExption`

To make things clear I'm using a Matlab method which is `Segseuil` and 
it returns a picture path `result`. I wanted to save this image for other users but the exception appears.

```
private void segmenter(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  {
 s.SegSeuil(0, (MWCharArray)name, (MWCharArray)result);
 BitmapImage tmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(result));  // exception here 
 image.Source = tmp;

}
```

Comment: What is the type of `result` and what is it value?

Comment: string result = "result.jpg";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If `result` is relative path**, for example **image.jpg** you must use `UriKind.Relative`:

```
BitmapImage tmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(result, UriKind.Relative));
```

or `RelativeOrAbsolute`:

```
BitmapImage tmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(result, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Make sure result file exist in your `.exe` file or in folder contains your exe file.

---

**If `result` is absolute path**, for example: **D:\image.jpg** you can use:

```
BitmapImage tmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(result));
```

or:

```
BitmapImage tmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(result, UriKind.Absolute));
```

or:

```
BitmapImage tmp = new BitmapImage(new Uri(result, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```